# When I update the site, the traffic goes down

Tags: traffic

Has it happened to you, you update the site create a whole new pages with a new better design the traffic goes down immediately?

What could the reason be? Could it be because significant traffic is caused by spammers robots and once you update contents, the old links with robots does not work hence you lose traffic? Or I am just wrong? Have you experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

If the URL of the page is the same the links have nothing to do with traffic going down. However the content of the page has a lot to do with it, meta tags specifically if you changed your title your rankings probably dropped. I'd wait to see if Google re-indexes you around the same position you were in.

If you updated your entire domain and didn't create 301 redirects and the URL structure changed of your entire site then it's common your traffic will go down. So if you changed your entire Domain and the URL's have changed setup redirects.

Comment: I think the title itself probably cant bring such an immediate change. I will setup 301 error and see what happens.

Comment: The title is extremely important if you changed it you most likely affected your rankings. You may come back up even above where you were but Google does take some time to re calculate where they want to rank you.

Comment: I have experienced this before several time but this time I will tell you, the old sit was really not professional. The new is great design and great contents. Just want to make a point. One would say aesthetic affect would have increased the hits and dicrease the bounce rate, not apparently.

Comment: Um no, the aesthetic affect will not increase your visits. No one is sitting at a desk in any Google office around the world saying this is a pretty site lets move it up in the SERPs. I know of sites which haven't had a face lift in 10 years that rank highly because of the quality of back links they've gained over the years.

Comment: I know that but I mean the visitor can at least click a couple of more links just because the site is more professional and friendly now but apparently it does not change things that quick.

Answer (score 0):

There are right ways and wrong ways to update content. As in the previous post, did you change the URI in the process.

Page updates can and frequently impact your rankings in Google and Bing sometimes up and sometimes down.

You need to check the referrer source of the page prior and after the content update to be sure of the cause.

If it is a loss in ogranic search traffic to the page, then you should engage a SEO expert to teach you how to update pages and not impact your search rankings (or even better improve them).